# Import Error using cPickle in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I am using Pickle in Python2.7. I am getting error while using `cPickle.load()` method. The code and error is shown below. Can someone guide me through this?

Code:

```
#! usr/bin/python
import cPickle
fo = open('result','rb')
dict1 = cPickle.load(fo)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 7, in <module>
dicts = cPickle.load(fo)
ImportError: No module named options
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can not do

```
import options
```

but when you or someone else did

```
cpickle.dump(xxx, open('result', 'rb'))
```

there was an object with a class or function of a module `options` that existed at this point in time, in `xxx`.

**Solution**

1. You can open the file binarily and replace `options` with the module you replaced the old module `options` with.
2. You probably created the file in your package like in module `package.main` by executing the file `main.py` or something like it, having a module `options` in the same directory.
   Now you do `import package.main`, try to read the file and `options` is now called `package.options` and the module `options` can not be found.
3. How did you create this file? How do you load it now? cPickle/pickle does not transfer source code - so if you use a function you need the module when you load it.