# python cPickle import error

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to run a python project. Some part of the code calls a serializer with the following code:

```
try:
    fo = open(data_file, "rb")
except IOError:
    print "Couldn't open data file: %s" % data_file
    return
try:
    myobject = pickle.load(fo)
except:
    fo.close()
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise

fo.close()
return myobject
```

When this part of the code is run, I get an error on

```
myobject = pickle.load(fo)
```

The error is:

```
myobject = pickle.load(fo)
File "/cs/local/lib/pkg/epd-7.3.1/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/cs/local/lib/pkg/epd-7.3.1/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "/cs/local/lib/pkg/epd-7.3.1/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "/cs/local/lib/pkg/epd-7.3.1/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
__import__(module)
ImportError: No module named label
```

I have looked at : [Import Error using cPickle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139583/import-error-using-cpickle-in-python)
but I cant use any of the solutions because:

1. "You can open the file binarily and replace options with the module you replaced the old module options with." => I dont know which binary file the solution is refering to. I dont seem to have any binary file in my package.
2. In my package, I dont have a module named label to import it.

   I'm very lost and I would appreciate any help, any suggestions.

Comment: what object are you trying to unpickle? can you show the content of the file?

Comment: Why can't you use any of the solutions proposed in that answer exactly?

Comment: data_file seems to be 2 .dat files.

Comment: Who created the pickled file? was it you?

Comment: No. I did not create any of the files or codes. I am given the whole package, and I was told it runs fine, but it gives me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pickle serializes an object, it serializes modules by reference.  So if you have a function or some other python object that has a call stack, it might refer to the module `label`, which cannot be found.  If you have a serialized class, class instance, function, or especially a closure… you might have a `import label` in the source code used to build that object.  a pickled object is a set of instructions for python for how to turn binary bits of information into a python object.  if some of the bits are missing, such as a module… (pickle again stores this by reference), then your unpickle will fail.

You could either try to install the `label` module, or you could ask the party who serialized the object to serialize it with a serializer that serializes the module itself instead of doing so by reference.  I think you can do this with the `dill` serializer.

If the person who serialized the object had `label` in their `globals`, and there was a closure being serialized, pickle includes everything in globals… so it might not even be relevant, but you'd need it do unserialize the object.  You could also ask for a re-pickle by a serializer that is more cautious about including globals, like `dill` or `cloudpickle`.

That's basically what [Import Error using cPickle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139583/import-error-using-cpickle-in-python) is saying in a less general way.